# What Constructor is being called, it's not move

Tags: c++, c++11

I created a basic test class to learn how the move constructor works. The move constructor does not seem to be called, and I'm not sure what constructor is actually called. If I use std::move then the move constructor is called, but a regular R value won't actually call it. Why is this happening, and what constructor is actually being called? I'm using g++ 4.6.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Test
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int* c;

public:
  Test(int one, int two)
  {
    std::cout << "Param Constructor" << "\n";
    a = one;
    b = two;
  }

  Test()
  {
    std::cout << "Default Constructor" << "\n";
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
  }

  ~Test()
  {
    std::cout << "Deconstructor" << "\n";
  }

  Test(const Test& test)
  {
    a = test.a;
    b = test.b;
    std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << "\n";
  }

  Test(Test&& test)
  {
    std::cout << "Move constructor called" << "\n";
    a = test.a;
    b = test.b;
  }

  Test& operator=(const Test& test)
  {
    std::cout << "in operator=" << "\n";
    a = test.a;
    b = test.b;
    return *this;
  }
};

Test createTest()
{
  return Test(1,2);
}

int main()
{
  Test test(createTest());
  Test test2 = test;
  std::cout << "After logic" << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get:

```
Param Constructor
Copy constructor called
After logic
Deconstructor
Deconstructor
```

I create an object of type Test with the name test, but there is no output of it being created? I was expecting this output:

```
Param Constructor
Move Constructor // (Missing)
Deconstructor //Deleting instance from createTest (Missing)
Copy constructor called
After logic
Deconstructor
Deconstructor
```

Comment: Copy elision. Compile with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: This actually illustrates a really awesome point: that calling `std::move` can actually be actively harmful in some cases. In particular, calling it either on the value of a return statement inside a function, or calling it on the return of the function call in the calling scope. Both of these things are already rvalues anyway, so there's no upside. But it can actually prevent copy elision, as you've witnessed. Move constructor may be better than copy constructor, but *no* constructor call is the fastest :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what constructor is actually being called?

No constructor at all. Count the number of destructor calls. You'll find that there is one less than you expected. The temporary that you expected to be constructed wasn't created at all.

> Why is this happening

The compiler avoided creation of the temporary. Instead, the object was constructed in place where it would have been moved to otherwise. This is known as copy elision.

Comment: Great answer, thank you :). I'll take a look into copy elision.